# EventStore - read specific time frame from stream

Tags: eventstoredb

I have a system that produces thousands of messages per hour. Some location tracking system that gather events from different devices and doing different calculations based on that messages.

I'm trying to evaluate if event store suites for this use case. So my plane is associate stream per device and accumulate messages in those streams.

Now the question - will I be able to read those messages for specific time frame in the past? I don't want to replay all the messages from the beginning, I just need fast access to messages from date1 to date2.

Any ideas? So far what I saw in the docs only relates to reading all messages either from the beginning or from the end and do the filtration during the process. But this pattern doesn't look very optimal to me. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EventStoreDB index allows you to read events from a specific stream by the event number, but not by date. What you wrote about reading from the beginning or the end is not entirely correct, as you can read from any position in the stream, both backwards and forwards, but then again it has nothing to do with dates.

Essentially, the data when the event was written to the database is considered not important and transient. For example, if you decide to move your data to another store using replication, all the events will get the new date. That's why if the date is important, it should be stored somewhere in the event data or metadata. EventStoreDB doesn't know about the event payload (or meta), and doesn't index that.

If you are looking to find a database kind that allows you to query records by time, the best chance is to look at time series databases like Prometheus and InfluxDB. These databases are specifically designed to index primarily by timestamp, and optimised to store data like sensor readings where each reading is a replacement of the previous one. EventStoreDB is not designed for that purpose, it's the database built to support event-sourced applications, and sensor readings is not that.

Comment: Thank much, @alexey-zimarev! It all make sense. As usual very detailed and helpful response. Will check those DBs.